# REST API for resources computed on the fly (that don't exist yet)

Tags: rest, api-design

(Hobby coder here please bear with me)

I tried searching for this but couldn't find a pattern or answer which confused me as this must be a common problem?

I'm writing a simple stock valuation service. My API takes a Stock symbol e.g. "stockdata/GOOG" and returns some calculated statistics. Of course underlying stock data changes frequently and so I need to recompute every now and then. I'm trying to work out how to handle 2 things elegantly

**1) User requests stock my service hasn't seen yet**: Given there are 10000s of securities it doesn't seem reasonable, or necessary, to go precompute them all. REST wise this confused me though as I understand I should really return 404 if I have no data. The thing is, assuming the stock is valid I'm able to fetch the underlying data and compute my own scores. How should I do this? Currently, I do refresh as a side effect, but that seems nasty. The only other REST method that comes to mind is to ask users to PUT/POST the symbol (no data) and this could trigger me to create/calculate. It just strikes me as odd as all examples I have seen include these methods providing a lot of extra data to present that resource. (All I need is the symbol itself and my service can do the rest. i.e. the GET contains all the information I need to calculate/create the resource)

**2) Refreshing state**: As data changes all the time I want to recompute but at max once per day as otherwise I hammer the source servers unnecessarily. As with the above how should I trigger refresh? At the moment, my GET checks currency and updates if it's older than a day, but again that doesn't seem RESTy. Should I just return stale data and again leave it to the user to make another call to request an update? Would this be a good use case for patch?

What do you recommend my payloads for these POST/PUT/PATCH should look like?

Thanks,
Sev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing "I have no cached data" with "there is no data". The clients don't really create or update the data, they want to get the latest version. A GET should work just fine. If you as a provider need to do some work in order to return the latest version then fine, it is still a GET.

The same applies to the updates. The users want the current version of the data, so they should use GET. If the data changes then they will get a new version, otherwise they will get an old version. Normal web pages work in the same way, the web server returns the current version and sometimes the data changes.

If you know when you will change the data it is good practice to return a Cache-Control header with a max-age or to use the Expires header or both. That way clients know they can cache the old data, but not forever.

Comment: Thank you that makes it clearer. I had an, unfounded, aversion to "writing" as part of a read. On this note, I've been looking for a pattern pseudo-code how to implement this "update while reading" data access pattern. Do you have any examples? (Ideally python)

Answer (score 1):

> The thing is, assuming the stock is valid I'm able to fetch the underlying data and compute my own scores. How should I do this? Currently, I do refresh as a side effect, but that seems nasty

Treating this as a `GET`, where the implementation has side effects on its own cache, is fine.  Here is Fielding supporting that position in 2002.

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that causes loss of property (money, BTW, is considered property for the
> sake of this definition).

The fact that you want to perform a bunch of side effects (reading some state, perhaps updating your local cache) is an implementation detail, and not of interest to the client.

> As data changes all the time I want to recompute but at max once per day as otherwise I hammer the source servers unnecessarily. As with the above how should I trigger refresh? At the moment, my GET checks currency and updates if it's older than a day, but again that doesn't seem RESTy.

The question you are asking is: how should your implementation manage its cache?  And the answer is pretty much "any way you want".  Storing an age for your most recently caculated result, and re-using it, is a perfectly normal thing to do.  It's really not the client's concern whether you are returning a cached representation, or a freshly computed one.

A question you are not asking: if you are only refreshing your local copy once a day, there's not a lot of point to the client checking for updates more often than that.  The HTTP standard includes [caching semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234), giving you a standard way of communicating freshness/invalidation semantics to the client.

Comment: Ah I hadn't thought of this as a caching problem, but I can see how it relates. To provide a bit more background my service does keep its own permanent record of values (in a database) as they change. Every day I store a set of values, so,, when I update" it's not an overwrite it's a new record. I struggle a bit drawing the line between a (volatile?)cache and my DB.